# Can you create a function to check multiple input values and change their style accordingly?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, input, simple-form

I am writing a form and I am trying to simplify my code into a function but cant figure it out.
This is javascript for a form filling out text inputs
is there a way to loop over all inputs to make sure they are filled and if one is not, change the style of that input box to a red color?
(not worried about the spans but if you have a solution I'm all ears, would also love to see a similar example)

```
but.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (firstname.value == "" || lastname.value == "") {
        
        firstname.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(200,0,0,.4)";
        lastname.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(200,0,0,.4)";
        span.style.display = "block";
        span.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid Name";
    }
    if (age.value == "" ){
        span.style.display = "block";
        age.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(200,0,0,.4)";
        span.innerHTML = "Please enter your age";
    }  if (isNaN(age.value) == true ){
        span.style.display = "block";
        age.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(200,0,0,.4)";
        span.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid Age";
    }  if (job.value == "") {
        span.style.display = "block";
        job.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(200,0,0,.4)";
        span.innerHTML = "Please enter a role";
    }  if (email.value == "") {
        span.style.display = "block";
        email.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(200,0,0,.4)";
        span.innerHTML = "Please enter an email";
    }  if (phone.value == "") {
        span.style.display = "block";
        phone.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(200,0,0,.4)";
        span.innerHTML = "Please enter phone number";
    }
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick for you, if you want to do it with a loop.

inputCollection is an array of all the elements which should be validated, which you pass into the function. The error span would be just the placeholder.
Personally i wouldn't add those styles via javascript and would use css for that matter.

```
function validateInputs(inputCollection, errorspan){
    for(let i = 0; i < inputCollection.Length; i++){
        let defaultValue = inputCollection[i].getAttribute('data-default');
        let errorMessage = inputCollection[i].getAttribute('data-errormessage');
        if(inputCollection[i].value === defaultValue || (!isNaN(defaultValue) && isNaN(inputCollection[i].value))){
            errorspan.innerHTML += `${errorMessage}`; 
        }          
    }
}
```

i wrote this without validating the code but it should help you out.

---

**Update 1**

To your questions:

The `data-default` attribute should be the default value, so for example a empty string for the name, a number for the age ect.

The `data-errormessage` attribute from my first reply would contain the detailed message, so your assumption is correct.

***Below you can find a snippet which should make the functionality more clearer***

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
/*collection of all elements which should be validated*/
    var col = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-default]');

    for(let i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
        let defaultValue = col[i].getAttribute('data-default');
        if(col[i].value === defaultValue || (!isNaN(defaultValue) && isNaN(col[i].value))){
            col[i].classList.add('hasError');
        }else if(col[i].classList.contains('hasError')){
            col[i].classList.remove('hasError');
        }          
    }
});
```

```css
.errormessage{
   display: none;
}
.hasError{
   background:#f00;
}

.hasError + span.errormessage{
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <input type='text' data-default="0" name='age' />
        <span class='errormessage' >some error message for the age</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <input type='text' data-default="" name='name' />
       <span class='errormessage' >some error message for the name</span>
    </div>
</form>
<button>validate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks man, Not working but I see where your going with it,
getting an error, unexpected end? but I cant find the problem.
I'm a but confused with what your doing with the variables in the loop,
what is defaultValue suppose to be? just an empty string? and  errorMessage as i understand would be putting  the error message in a data class within html 
and yes It probably would have been easier to just use a css class for the styling